# Youtube_DL download format (python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, youtube-dl

Whilst reading through the Youtube_DL docs I saw an option for `format` and don't quite understand what it means and I cannot find the `options.py` file too.

```
 |  format:            Video format code. See options.py for more information.
```

This is a quiet module and little posts exist (from what I can find) so for who knows about it - is this something you give the `YoutubeDL` class in the dictionary of options? Like this:

```
youtube_dl.YoutubeDL({'format':'mp3'})
```

Answer (score 1):

Format refers to "video format options", if we look at options.py you'll see the argument option added [here](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/youtube_dl/options.py#L388) says `help='Video format code, see the "FORMAT SELECTION" for all the info')`.

So yeah, you can read more about it in the [FORMAT SELECTION](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#format-selection)

Comment: Do you know how I could implement this if it is possible (changing the download file extension or format)?

Comment: @Crawley The second example in the [embedding instructions](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#embedding-youtube-dl) downloads videos as mp3. If your goal is not mp3 files, edit your goal into the question.

Answer (score 1):

Video Format Options:

`-f, --format FORMAT              Video format code, see the "FORMAT SELECTION" for all the info`

```
-F, --list-formats               List all available formats of requested videos
```

from the manual you can use it as follow :

`youtube-dl -F link_to_video`

you will get all formats available in the video with a format code then you choose your requested format and download the video

```
youtube-dl -f format_code link_to_video
```

Comment: I forgot to mention I was using python :) would this still be the same kind of structure - find out what formats are available for the video and then download one?

Comment: yes it's the same instruction just put python youtube-dl [OPTIONS] URL